# Batch Output Painting Mockup

Tags: workflow

I have a job to do: I need to produce mockups for a series of paintings.
I have a scene set up with the painting on the wall as shown below.
This painting is simply a material with an image texture.
I have 200 paintings to display on the wall.

I want to render a JPG of the scene with each painting, for 200 total different JPGs.
What would be the fastest way to do this?
I figure it would be to code through python.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if this is the angle you are going to have for the final render(s) - camera is facing the frame straight on, no parallax - then this could just be a matter of using the compositor or VSE:

1. Render your final render, by itself. Save to a file.
2. Open a new blend file and choose the "Video Editing" preset.
3. Add your final render to the VSE sequencer.
4. Get all the images you want to superimpose, and copy them in a single folder. Give each one a similar filename along with a number in a range. Say you have 200 photos. In the folder, name them "superimposed_001.jpg", "superimposed_002.jpg", and so on to "superimposed_200.jpg".
5. Add an "image sequence" strip to Blender's VSE sequencer - which is really just the sequence of image files we just copied.
6. Overlay it on top of the final render in the VSE, using transforms to get the scale and position just right (and assuming your images are all the same aspect ratio and/or resolution, you'd only need to do this once for the whole image sequence)
7. Render out as an image sequence of animations - now each resulting frame is for a different image!

Here's an example of the strip - you only need the final render and sequence of paintings on top, the scaling and position is built into the strips (the image sequence I used got messed up, but you can get the idea):

[image: VSE playing image sequence on top of image]

If the frame is viewed at an angle - you will need to distort the superimposed images first. You can render a new copy of the paintings in the compositor with the distortion:

1. Open a new Blender file, open up the compositor
2. Import your painting image sequence (made using step 4 above)
3. Using your final render as a reference, use the "Corner Pin" node to distort the painting to match the distortion. Don't worry about using the Vector inputs - you can drag the "x"s at the corners to where you want in the backdrop viewer :)
4. You can either: do all your editing and rendering from the compositor, or render *just the distorted paintings* as an image sequence. Then you can use the steps above to put them together in the VSE.

Here's the example of the compositor:
[image: Corner pin node in compositor]

Comment: Unfortunately I found these directions a bit difficult to understand but I was able to get far enough with simply using an image sequence node to feed the images to Cycles for rendering one at a time, as an animation. However, I don't want Cycles to need to re-render each frame when the only difference is the painting. I've hit the "Persistent Data" checkbox to try and avoid this but it still seems to be rendering the rest of the scene over and over. Is there any way around this?

Comment: To clarify, my method isn't re-rendering each Cycles frame of the background - you'll render it once, then use VSE in a separate file to render out the images with it. I can update it for clarification.

Comment: That would be helpful as I am having trouble. We have 1 scene shot from a camera angle that faces it straight on, but another one that takes a picture from an angle. Any chance you'd be open to making a quick screen recording of the steps?

Comment: I updated with a couple images and better steps. I won't be able to make a full video recording, hopefully this is enough for you to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your time!